# generate findbug html report in maven

Tags: maven, findbugs

How can I generate find bug html report?

I added the following in  AND

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludeFilterFile>findbugsExclude.xml</excludeFilterFile>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        <effort>Max</effort>
        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
        <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I do `mvn findbugs:findbugs`, I get the xml report.

When I do `mvn site`, I get some other errors.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the errors you get when running mvn site?